# I was set values in session when user on first page when he click the back button session variables also set with i

Tags: javascript, php, session-variables

**this is my code how to use this code when user click back button**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Seats']))
{
    $Eventid = $_SESSION['Eventid'];
    $stmt = $con->prepare(
        'UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`=" " where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`=? AND `Status`="Hold" '
    );
    $stmt->bind_param(
         "st",$_SESSION['Eventid'],
          $_SESSION['Seats']
    );
    $stmt->execute();
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
}
```

Comment: What is "i"? Can you summarize your question in the title and formulate it in full within the question body? That should make it more clear what you like to ask abozut.

Comment: "i" means "it". i just miss the word to right.i was execute the same query on second page.when user click the back button on browser it went back to first page in this time i want to execute same query on first page

Comment: When the user presses the back button, the previous page is normally delivered from cache, so no query at all will be executed. Try with shift reload. Also output some debug information so that you know that the value is the one you expect to be. Not that the problem is with session persistence (and not the database part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the session has started first.

```
if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

If not the start it.